# json_encode with option JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

Tags: php, json

When using echo json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

I get the this error

> **Warning**:  json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Comment: The `options` parameter was added in PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: And JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE added in PHP 5.4.0

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498286/why-does-the-php-json-encode-function-convert-utf-8-strings-to-hexadecimal-entit

Answer (score 8):

Your php version might be too low:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 ] )

5.3.0    The options parameter was added
```

Comment: hmm ok and if this is the case how i can do same thing but with different script

Comment: At http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php there is a comment with "Simple replacement for JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE (PHP < 5.4 for example)"

Comment: @EvenJohnson. `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` probably isn't actually necessary. If your version of PHP is too low, just do without it.

Comment: Hmm, 5 upvotes and "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors" :)

Answer (score 4):

See patch at http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/issues/detail?id=22 which allows the same functionality on PHP 5.2.

Basically run something like this:

```
foreach ($array as &$val) {
    $val = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i',
        function($matches) {
            return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $matches[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
        }, $val);
}
```

Comment: Even this comes close, this is technically wrong. Also PHP 5.4 has a bug here, see [PHP Bug #62010 json_decode produces invalid byte-sequences](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62010)