# Why does the PHP json_encode function convert UTF-8 strings to hexadecimal entities?

Tags: php, encoding, json

I have a PHP script that deals with a wide variety of languages. Unfortunately, whenever I try to use `json_encode`, any Unicode output is converted to hexadecimal entities. Is this the expected behavior? Is there any way to convert the output to UTF-8 characters?

Here's an example of what I'm seeing:

INPUT

```
echo $text;
```

OUTPUT

```
База данни грешка.
```

INPUT

```
json_encode($text);
```

OUTPUT

```
"\u0411\u0430\u0437\u0430 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u0438 \u0433\u0440\u0435\u0448\u043a\u0430."
```

Answer (score 495, accepted):

Since PHP/5.4.0, there is an option called `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. Check it out:

https://php.net/function.json-encode

Therefore you should try:

```
json_encode( $text, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

Comment: Aha. Thanks! I should have read the documentation more carefully. Thanks.

Comment: JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE was introduced in PHP 5.4.0, and is unavailable in earlier versions. When using it in earlier versions you will get this error: "Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in ...". See CertaiN's answer below for 5.3 solution.

Comment: This also works with Danish letters Æ,æ,Ø,ø,Å,å
Thank you!

Answer (score 64):

JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE is available on PHP Version 5.4 or later.
The following code is for Version 5.3.

**UPDATED**

- `html_entity_decode` is a bit more efficient than `pack` + `mb_convert_encoding`.
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` skips backslashes itself and specified characters by `JSON_HEX_*` flags.

```
function raw_json_encode($input, $flags = 0) {
    $fails = implode('|', array_filter(array(
        '\\\\',
        $flags & JSON_HEX_TAG ? 'u003[CE]' : '',
        $flags & JSON_HEX_AMP ? 'u0026' : '',
        $flags & JSON_HEX_APOS ? 'u0027' : '',
        $flags & JSON_HEX_QUOT ? 'u0022' : '',
    )));
    $pattern = "/\\\\(?:(?:$fails)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|u([0-9a-fA-F]{4}))/";
    $callback = function ($m) {
        return html_entity_decode("&#x$m[1];", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    };
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, json_encode($input, $flags));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the \u be \U i.e. uppercase?

Comment: Nice solution for PHP < 5.4 ;)

Comment: I was looking for 3 days to find this solution for Version 5.3 as my host didn't upgrade to 5.4. To me you are a Life saver and for being so complete I would rather mark this as accepted answer!

Comment: Fixed bug when string contains `\\ `. Newer version grabs `\\ ` on higher priority than `\u`.

Comment: This should be added in the php library. Good Job.

Answer (score 15):

You like to set charset and unescaped unicode

```
 header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');  
 json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 6):

One solution is to first encode data and then decode it in the same file:

```
$string =json_encode($input, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) ; 
echo $decoded = html_entity_decode( $string );
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my combined solution for various PHP versions.

In my company we are working with different servers with various PHP versions, so I had to find solution working for all.

```
$phpVersion = substr(phpversion(), 0, 3)*1;

if($phpVersion >= 5.4) {
  $encodedValue = json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
} else {
  $encodedValue = preg_replace('/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e', "iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8',pack('V', hexdec('U$1')))", json_encode($value));
}
```

Credits should go to [Marco Gasi](https://www.experts-exchange.com/members/marqusG.html) & [abu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/710788/abu). The solution for PHP >= 5.4 is provided in the json_encode docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
json_encode($text, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score -2):

The raw_json_encode() function [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16498714/710788) did not solve me the problem (for some reason, the callback function raised an error on my PHP 5.2.5 server).

But this other solution did actually work.

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28628085/json-encode-fails-with-special-characters.html

Credits should go to [Marco Gasi](https://www.experts-exchange.com/members/marqusG.html). I just call his function instead of calling json_encode():

```
function jsonRemoveUnicodeSequences( $json_struct )
{ 
    return preg_replace( "/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e", "iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8',pack('V', hexdec('U$1')))", json_encode( $json_struct ) );
}
```

Answer (score -6):

> Is this the expected behavior?

the `json_encode()` only works with UTF-8 encoded data.

maybe you can get an answer to convert it here: [cyrillic-characters-in-phps-json-encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410704/cyrillic-characters-in-phps-json-encode)