# json_encode returns JSON_ERROR_UTF8 when converting array to JSON

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, json

I'm trying to convert an array with values in brazilian portuguese to JSON.

Here is an array example:

```
array(1) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(77) "Cartão Credicard Universitário Visa Crédito "
}
```

If I use `mb_detect_encoding` it shows that all values and keys are either in ASCII or UTF8.

However if I try to use `json_encode`in order to generate the json, it returns a false and `json_last_error` function says that the error is `JSON_ERROR_UTF8`

But if I apply first the `utf8_encode_deep` function to the array ( http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php ), the json is generated without giving any errors.

The problem with this solution is that it returns certain words with bad codification.

Example:

Word before applying `utf8_encode`: Cartão (good codification)

Word after applying `utf8_encode`: CartÃ£o (bad codification)

So although it generates the JSON, it doesn't solve my problem because it messes up the words.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
try {
  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
  $sql = "SELECT title FROM card";
  $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);

  $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json = $json_encode($result);
  $error = json_last_error();

  var_dump($json, $error === JSON_ERROR_UTF8);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage() . '\n';
}
```

If I try to connect to the database using charset=utf8 or charset=utf8mb4, it retrieves `CartÃ£o`(bad codification), instead of `Cartão` (good codification)

I have also tried to use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` as parameter of `json_encode`, but the result remains the same as without using this parameter.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**: I've simplified the example with one concrete case where this problem is happening.

**UPDATE 2**: Added some code in order to clarify the example, also added some explanations about possible solutions in the comments.

Comment: Well, where are the values coming from? Can you narrow it down to one specific value that's causing the issue? Once you've narrowed it down, do `bin2hex($value)` on that value to see its bytes. Check an encoding table if those bytes are correct for UTF-8 for the characters you expect.

Comment: The values are coming from a mysql query where the database and table character set are utf8 and collation is utf8_general_ci. The specific problem  seems to happen only with the vocals with tildes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde (as in the example shown in my question)

Comment: Tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the PHP json\_encode function convert UTF-8 strings to hexadecimal entities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498286/why-does-the-php-json-encode-function-convert-utf-8-strings-to-hexadecimal-entit)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "If I try to connect to the database using charset=utf8 or charset=utf8mb4, it retrieves CartÃ£o(bad codification), instead of Cartão (good codification)"

You are using latin1 as the display encoding, so that UTF-8 encoded, correct, text is displayed incorrectly.

Add `charset=utf8` to the connection string and also set the response charset to UTF-8:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
```