# Thai language JSON decode not working

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have an array in PHP which has values in Thai language.
when I use `json_encode` to pass values in javascript only `json_decode` does not gives the output ,returns blank.

`print_r ($myarray)` this returns output in Thai language.

`json_encode($myarray)` returns output '`\u0e23`'.
How to convert it to Thai language output .

Comment: Add complete code. Your JSON object and how you're encoding/decoding it

Comment: are the contents encoded? http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: Can you check the encoding of one of the strings in Thai. I had a similar problem before with Chinese language.

Comment: `\u0e23` is a Thai character, represented as a Unicode escape. Try this: `echo json_decode('"\u0e23"');`

Comment: @Amadan yes it is working i was missing double quotes. I have to send an object  .`json_decode` gives warning it accepts only string not an array so any idea ? how to send an object

Comment: JSON is a string, always. What kind of object are you trying to send to `json_decode`? It would be much better if you posted a snippet of your code that demonstrates your error.

Comment: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/2sL9mLyq/  this kind of object

Comment: That is not valid PHP. How are you passing that to `json_decode`, if not as a string?!? Again, post the snippet of code that you are executing, because this makes no sense. If I do `print_r(json_decode('...what you posted...'));`, I am getting a perfectly fine PHP structure, with Thai strings no less.

Comment: my basic need is i have to display thai characters in javascript on phonegap app , so I was using  `json_encode` in php to receive data in my app to display those thai characters but it is displaying like this   `/u0e23` in my app and on php side it is displaying like this `\u0e23`, i just tried `json_decode`   to get the desired output but it did not work what you tried .

Answer (score 1):

The function itself [modifies the codification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498286/why-does-the-php-json-encode-function-convert-utf-8-strings-to-hexadecimal-entit) the string.

Use this as a second parameter: `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

```
 json_encode( $myarray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

Check out the [constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) and choose the best for you.