# PHP: simplexml_load_file gets strange characters from an XML file with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, simplexml, php-5.4, symfony-2.7

The simplexml_load_file() function doesn't parse the accent characters well. The file is UTF-8 encoded, the xml tag has encoding="UTF-8".

I'm importing an XML file encoded in UTF-8 with simplexml_load_file() function. This file has some accent characters, and when I do a print_r() or var_dump() the accent characters are converted to strange characters.

First line in XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

In code I'm running the basic

```
$xFile = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile)
```

I'm looping through the SimpleXML Object and fetching the word with accent characters like so

```
$text = (string)$p->i
```

Now

```
var_dump($text);
```

shows `Ge├»rriteerd` instead of `Geïrriteerd`

I've tried to get_file_contents() and then simplexml_load_string() and 
I've also tried to load the XML file with DOMDocument, but the same 'wild' characters are being displayed.

Any thoughts on what else could I do?

Note: I'm working on PHP5.4, that's the PROD version and I can't change it.

Comment: _"when I do a print_r() or var_dump()"_  assuming you're looking at this in your browser, have you made sure to set the page charset correctly? See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: The var_dump() it's in a console (ssh), because the parsing is done in a cronjob.

Comment: Ok, so what's the encoding in your console?

Comment: The console encoding was indeed one of the issues, after that I've identified a ```json_encode()``` that was converting the UTF-8 chars to hexadecimals.
I've fixed that by passing ```JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE``` as a second param to the ```json_encode()```.
Source of fix : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498286/why-does-the-php-json-encode-function-convert-utf-8-strings-to-hexadecimal-entit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a windows console default encoding.
I've changed the encoding to UTF-8 by running `chcp 65001`.

@Phil's comment was helpful.