# Can't fetch data on php server, via javascript;

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I have PHP server on my localhost.
And file with following script:

```
?php
include 'config.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli(GGC_HOST , GGC_USER , GGC_PASSWORD , GGC_DB);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("Connect failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
    }//if

    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    $queryString="SELECT Id, name, description, price, old FROM fruits;";


    $myArray=array();   

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($queryString)) {

        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
        }//while
   }//if
    echo json_encode($myArray);

$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

When I try to run my php file in browser, it gives me some result, like this:

> [{"Id":"1","name":"\u10d5\u10d0\u10e8\u10da\u10d8","description":"\u10d1\u10e0\u10dd\u10ea\u10d9\u10d8
>   I
>   \u10ee\u10d0\u10e0\u10d8\u10e1\u10ee\u10d8\u10e1","price":"1.25","old":"0"},{"Id":"2","name":"\u10db\u10e1\u10ee\u10d0\u10da\u10d8","description":"\u10d2\u10e3\u10da\u10d0\u10d1\u10d8
>   \u10d5\u10d0\u10dc\u10d8\u10e1","price":"3.5","old":"0"}]

My first question is: Why it shows it so strange in browser, and how to fix it?

when I fetch data from JavaScript:

```
fetch('http://localhost/aaa/fruits.php', {
                method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
                mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
                    // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                  },
                // Useful for including session ID (and, IIRC, authorization headers)
              })
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {
                console.log(data) // Prints result from `response.json()`
              })
              .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Console shows me:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>       at index.js:156

I can't solve this problem during 3 days and decided to share with you. 
156th line is:

```
.then(response => response.json())
```

Comment: did you try the optional argument of JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE on php ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498286/why-does-the-php-json-encode-function-convert-utf-8-strings-to-hexadecimal-entit

Comment: I can also perfectly use JSON.parse on your input, doesnt throw any error whatsover.

Comment: Try to remove `?>` from your PHP script.

Comment: @ ibrahim tanyalcin I checked the version of PHP and it is 5.5.17, besides your splution doesn't fix

Comment: `echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`